# Installing Node.js with yum on Amazon CentOS - libssl error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, centos, gruntjs, yum

We are using CentOS as elastic build agent for Bamboo on demand. 
Recently we utilized grunt for processing our JavaScript files. So I am trying to install npm and grunt in startup script.

Original solution was taken  from https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

```
curl -O http://download-i2.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install npm --enablerepo=epel
npm install -g grunt
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

And it worked for some time. But later it start fail on yum with error related to missed libssl.so.10.

I checked and libssl.so.10 present in the system.

yum install libssl.so.10 ->

Package openssl-1.0.0g-1.26.amzn1.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

yum install libcrypto.so.10 ->
Package openssl-1.0.0g-1.26.amzn1.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

yum install nodejs ->

Error: Package: nodejs-0.10.24-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: nodejs-0.10.24-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)

The most interesting part that on the same machine I absolutely successfully compiled nodes from sources using

```
git clone http://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
make install
```

Eventually it takes too long to make nodejs upon each elastic agent start. So I am still seeking for  a way to install node.js with yum. Can you provide any ideas about directions to evaluate?

Maybe there is some other way to install npm and grunt at CentOS?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this problem? I'm running into the same issue, and the remove and install of libcrypto and libssl didn't help.

Comment: we are working on migrating to Ubuntu instead

Comment: Also I managed to clone node.js from github and make it  with make ( it is slow - takes about 30 min), but it works

Comment: I finally gave up and switch to Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you remove the node.js when it started giving you problems?  Try force remove the ssl and crypto packages and reinstalled them.

```
yum remove libssl.so.10
yum remove libcrypto.so.10 
yum install libssl.so.10
yum install libcrypto.so.10
```

It sounds like your library files are not there when you get the errors but the rpm itself is installed. You have to remove the rpm first before you can reinstall.

Comment: I am using Atlassian stock image for elastic agent at AWS. Upon each agent start I am starting from clean CentOS and setup all dependencies in agent startup script. But it is good idea to try force reinstall after adding epel repo to yum.

Comment: It should be fine as long as you clean up everything related to node.js first.